# No idea how to handle an error while calling substring on a sql variable

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, error-handling

I'm trying to figure out how to handle an error that gets thrown at the final set statement, wherein I call substring on the current @return value and set the result the same return value.

The stored procedure takes in a string of numbers like this: '135, 34, 21,'. The trailing comma is an artifact of a poorly designed system. This procedure runs the string through a split function to create a temp table, and then does a look up on each of the items in the string, returning a name associated with each of the three values. The error is thrown when all three values of the parameter are 0: '0,0,0,'

I'm just crap with SQL Server and have no idea how to gracefully handle those situations. Could someone provide some advice for me?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
declare @positions table
    (orderID int identity(1,1), positionID int)
declare @counter int
declare @positionMax int
declare @currentPositionID int
declare @return varchar(max)

set @counter = 1
set @return = ''

insert @positions
select items
from dbo.Split(
    (select Positions
     from dbo.athletes
     where athleteID = 3701, ',')

select @positionMax = max(orderID) 
from @positions

while(@counter <= @positionMax)
begin
    select @currentPositionID = tp.PositionID
    from db.positions tp
        inner join @positions p
            on tp.PositionID = p.positionID
    where p.orderID = @counter

    select @return = @return + PositionName + ', '
    from dbo.positions
    where PositionID = @currentPositionID

    set @counter = @counter + 1
end

set @return = substring(@return, 1, (len(@return) - 1))

select @return
```

#### Edit with sample data and expected results

Here's what the positions table looks like:

```
PositionId, PositionName
1, Defensive End
2, Quarterback
3, Pitcher
4, Catcher
5, First Base
```

The positions are saved in a single table row like this:

```
1,2,3,
1,0,0,
0,0,0,
```

The output would look like this:

> ```
> Defensive End, Quarterback, Pitcher
> Defensive End
> No position selected
> ```

"No position selected" is what I'd like to have output in the instance of three zeros.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Absolutely, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your error is caused because @return is 0 characters long. A simple option could be to add the value 0, 'No position selected' to the positions table.

A nicer option could be to add an IF statement around the set statement:

```
if len(@return) > 0
BEGIN
    set @return = substring(@return, 1, (len(@return) - 1))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    set @return = 'No position selected'
END
```

You could also add a Try/Catch block if using SQL to catch any generic exceptions. See [msdn try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

Also, not sure why you're doing the while loop. There are generally better options in SQL like using a CTE.

Comment: If you add that row to the positions table, you won't get 'No position selected', you'll get 'No position selected, No position selected, No position selected' ...

Comment: I knew there was some way to do this. I just couldn't think through it in SQL. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it without the split function and without the loop. Note that this doesn't turn out in the exact order of your expected output.

```
DECLARE @pos TABLE
(
    PositionId   INT,
    PositionName VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT @pos SELECT 1, 'Defensive End'
UNION ALL   SELECT 2, 'Quarterback'
UNION ALL   SELECT 3, 'Pitcher'
UNION ALL   SELECT 4, 'Catcher'
UNION ALL   SELECT 5, 'First Base';

DECLARE @row TABLE(pList VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @row SELECT '1,2,3,'
UNION ALL   SELECT '1,0,0,'
UNION ALL   SELECT '0,0,0,';

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT x.pList, p.PositionName 
    FROM @row AS x LEFT OUTER JOIN @pos AS p 
    ON ',' + x.pList LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), p.PositionID) + ',%'
)
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + PositionName 
      FROM cte AS cte2 WHERE cte.pList = cte2.pList
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]',N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''), ''), 
      'No position selected'
  )
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY pList;
```

**EDIT**

Here is a slightly different version that seems to obey the order in the original list and relies on a numbers table...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(n INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT dbo.Numbers(n) SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER
 (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2;
```

...and the `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` hint:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pList ORDER BY n.n) 
        FROM @row AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN @pos AS p
    ON ',' + r.pList + ',' LIKE '%,' + RTRIM(p.PositionId) + ',%'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Numbers AS n
    ON n.n = CHARINDEX(',' + RTRIM(p.PositionId) + ',', ',' + r.pList + ',')
)
SELECT pList, Position = COALESCE(STUFF((SELECT ',' + PositionName 
    FROM cte AS cte2 INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers AS n ON n.n = cte2.r
    WHERE cte2.pList = cte.pList FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''), 'No position selected')
FROM cte GROUP BY pList OPTION (FORCE ORDER);
```

This relies on the assumption that the optimizer will choose the clustered primary key on the numbers table. To enforce this further it may make sense to ensure that that index is used by naming it using the `WITH (INDEX)` hint on both of the joins to `dbo.Numbers` (which means you should probably name the primary key constraint vs. doing it the lazy way like I did above).

Sorry it took me a bit to come back to this.

Comment: I like the idea of no loops, however, the order that they're returned is important. Thank you for taking time to answer.

Comment: @MrGrigg how do you define the order in the original table (`1,2,3,`, `1,0,0,`...)? A table is just an unordered set of rows unless you have some defined way to specify the order.

Comment: Maybe we're not talking about the same order. The order I need is specified by the single comma delimited data row. '1,3,2,' specifies the order. So the output would need to read 'Defensive End, Pitcher, Quarterback'

Comment: The comma-separated list of words will come out in the same order as they are specified in the numbers. The order I'm talking about that is not defined is whether the *row* representing 1,2,3 will come before or after the *row* representing 1,0,0.

Comment: Awesome, Aaron, thanks. Do you think there's real performance value in using your solution without loops and splits?

Comment: I don't know your system well enough. You'll have to test the performance yourself, unfortunately, as it will depend on whether your system is CPU/I/O/Memory bound, disk architecture, usage patterns, concurrency, locking, size of table, indexes, etc. Way too many variables. Also note that this doesn't use a function and doesn't use an *explicit* loop, but just because it doesn't say `WHILE` doesn't mean there isn't any looping going on under the covers. The `FOR XML PATH` could certainly be considered a cursor in disguise.

Comment: And actually, the code sample I posted does not obey the order e.g. `1,3,2` ... if you are interested in this solution (it seems you've already accepted another one), let me know and I can see if I can figure out a way to coerce the order.

Comment: @MrGrigg I've updated my answer with a version that seems to obey the string order in the original list, at least in the sample given (the optimizer may decide to do different things if the list is extremely large).

Answer (score 1):

Please try there

--------------sample table ---------------------------------------

```
create table #tmp_table (PositionId int, PositionName varchar(50))

insert into #tmp_table values (1, 'Defensive End')
insert into #tmp_table values (2, 'Quarterback')
insert into #tmp_table values (3, 'Pitcher')
insert into #tmp_table values (4, 'Catcher')
insert into #tmp_table values (5, 'First Base')

create table #postition (post varchar(20))
insert into #postition values ('1,2,3,')
insert into #postition values ('1,0,0,')
insert into #postition values ('0,0,0,')
```

----------------------------------stored procedure -------------------------------

```
-- temp result table
create table #tmp_result (post_list varchar(2000))

DECLARE post_cursor CURSOR 
    STATIC READ_ONLY
    FOR 
    select post     
    from #postition

-- temp variable
declare @post varchar(20)

OPEN post_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM post_cursor INTO @post

-- remove last comma
SET @post = LEFT(@post,LEN(@post) - 1)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
    exec (
            '
            insert into #tmp_result(post_list)
            SELECT STUFF(
            (
                SELECT '','' + PositionName
                FROM #tmp_table C
                WHERE positionId in (' + @post + ')
                FOR XML PATH('''')
            ), 1, 1, '''') 
        ')
    -- fetch again
    FETCH NEXT FROM post_cursor INTO @post

    SET @post = LEFT(@post,LEN(@post) - 1)  

END

CLOSE post_cursor
DEALLOCATE post_cursor


-- return result
select *
from #tmp_result
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a response. I am so unfamiliar with SQL that I don't really understand what you're suggestiong.